# Shorthand for VB.net class constructors

Tags: vb.net

I tend to make a bunch of POD classes for holding various data and they usually look like this:

```
Public class vertex
    public x as single
    public y as single
    Public sub New(x as single, y as single)
        Me.x = x
        Me.y = y
    End Sub
End class
```

Is there any way to not have to write out me.class_variable_name = function_variable_with_same_name? or some shorter way to do it?

Might seem like a pointless question but i tend to make those kinds of classes all the time and it just feels so reduntant writing the same variable names over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx) to skip the constructor entirely:

```
Public Class vertex
    Public Property x As Single
    Public Property y As Single
End Class


Dim v As New vertext() With {.x = 2, .y = 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a constructor? Plus you can narrow the scope of the variables if you don't need or want to expose them.

```
Dim v As New vertext(2, 4)

Public class vertex
 Private x as single
 Private y as single
 Public sub New(x as single, y as single)
    Me.x = x
    Me.y = y
 End Sub
End class
```

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, how do you plan to access these variables off `v`?

Comment: This pattern is for times when they only need to be access internally - it happens. Limiting the scope to the tightest level is always a good practice. It's just an option.

Comment: I understand when such concept would be useful. It just looks odd as it is currently written.